# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 and Entity Framework 7 issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

We can't add Owin and Entity framework 7 together. As we do so then there will be ambiguity between Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.core 2.0.0.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 3.0.0 Beta1

And hence I am not able to implement role provider in my application to manage the user roles.

After facing this issue I removed Owin references and created UserManager using
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 3.0.0 and EF 7 but UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName) always throws exception as below:-

> *InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Mozaics.DAL.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another
>   instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. For
>   new entities consider using an IIdentityGenerator to generate unique
>   key values.*

Code snippet is like this.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {
        var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

        var result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,  RoleName );

        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
        var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }
```

Comment: In Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core Library the method is like this

UserManager.AddRoleToUserAsync(User.Id, RoleName)

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide us with your `project.json` as well as your runtime in your project properties and the output of `dnvm list`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@sanjaypujari

Just try that one:

```
var user = await context.FindByNameAsync(UserName);
ApplicationUser appuser = (ApplicationUser)user;
var result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(appuser,  RoleName);
```

When executed like this, ApplicationUser shouldn't be tracked twice.
Same thing helps, too, if you want to update a ApplicationUser.

Answer (score 0):

I run to this issue.  One solution that worked for me was that getting the user via the UserManager and then adding the role:

**instead of**

```
var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
var result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,  RoleName );
```

**use the following**

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName);
var result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,  RoleName );
```